# Backbone jquery mobile rendering - in CoffeeScript

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm appending a template to the body, this renders fine in jquery mobile. However, I then loop through data and render individual views - where jquery mobile now fails..

Originally I use listview("refresh"), however I get this error, "**jquerymobile error “cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization**" when looping through an entirely new view... Also implementing trigger("create") also doesn't seem to work wherever I put it... Maybe I'm wrong, if so can you show me where to put it, or explain how this may be fixed...

Another question has suggested doing this... but I'm not sure where to place it, and if it works:

```
$('#myListview').bind('pageinit', function() {
  $('#myListview').listview('refresh');
});
```

I'm really stuck.. Can anyone shed some light on how to get round this problem, thanks!

My main view looping through smaller views is..

```
class FavouritesListView extends Backbone.View
    initialize: =>
        Favourites.fetch()

    template: _.template($('#propertyFavourites').html())

    render: =>
        $(@el).append(@template)
        @addFavs()

    addFavs: =>
        Favourites.each (fav) =>
            view = new FavouriteView({model: fav})
            $("#favList", @el).append(view.render().el)

            #I've tried $("#favList", @el).append(view.render().el).listview("refresh") & get "cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization".. I've also tried .trigger("create") which doesn't work..
```

My list item view is (which is being rendered without styles)...

```
class FavouriteView extends Backbone.View
    template: _.template($('#propertyFav').html())

    render: =>
        $(@el).html(@template({row: @model}))
        @
```

My router and app are loaded like so..

```
class AppRouter extends Backbone.Router
    routes:
        "": "home"
        "favourites": "favourites"

    initialize: ->
        #handle back buttons
        $('.back').live('click', (event) -> 
            window.history.back();
            false
        )
        @firstPage = true;

    home: ->
        @changePage(new HomeView())

    favourites: ->
        @changePage(new FavouritesListView())

    changePage: (page, theTransition) ->
        $(page.el).attr('data-role', 'page')
        page.render()
        $('body').append($(page.el))

        if theTransition is undefined
            transition = $.mobile.defaultPageTransition
        else
            transition = theTransition

        #We don't want the first page to slide in
        if @firstPage
            transition = 'none'
            @firstPage = false

        $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {changeHash: false, transition: transition})


$(document).ready( ->
    AppRouter = new AppRouter()
    Backbone.history.start()
)
```

For reference I'm using jqm 1.2.0 Alpha...

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be wiping out your `listview` every time you run the `render` method in `FavouritesListView`.  Every time you are creating a new `<ul>` you have to re-trigger `create` on it.  Ideally, you would keep that `ul` element around and only swap out the inner `li` elements when your `fetch` is done.  Then do the `$('#favList').listview('refresh')` when they've been stuck in there.

But, that would require some significant rework, so, give this a try instead with your existing code:

```
class FavouritesListView extends Backbone.View
    initialize: =>
        Favourites.fetch()

    template: _.template($('#propertyFavourites').html())

    render: =>
        @$el.append(@template)
        @addFavs()

    addFavs: =>
        # FYI: @$(...) is shorthand for this.$el.find(...)
        $favList = @$("#favList")
        Favourites.each (fav) =>
            view = new FavouriteView({model: fav})

            # TODO: batch these up and only do one append at the end for better performance.
            $favList.append(view.render().el)

        # Move this trigger out of the for loop, only trigger at the end.
        # Sometimes triggering create on the parent is better, not the actual list.
        @$el.trigger "create"
```

I've also tweaked some things based on some new Backbone features like `this.$el === $(this.el)` and `this.$(...) === this.$el.find(...)` being equivalent shorthands that are better to use.